# How to convert str to int from a file csv

Tags: string, csv, int

I am training with Python and in an exercise I am supposed to open a file .csv and to find how many times in a file recurs the name "Max" in California("CA") between 1950 and 2000. This is what I done:

```
import csv
counter = 0


for line in file:
    counter = counter + 1
    line_splitted = line.strip().split(",")
    if line_splitted[1] == "Max":
        print(line_splitted)
```

An extract of the output (the entries are many more) is:

```
['17261', 'Max', '1965', 'M', 'AK', '6']
['20094', 'Max', '1983', 'M', 'AK', '5']
['20291', 'Max', '1984', 'M', 'AK', '5']
['20604', 'Max', '1986', 'M', 'AK', '10']
['20786', 'Max', '1987', 'M', 'AK', '10']
```

Then I wrote:

```
if line_splitted[1] == "Max" and line_splitted[2] >= 1950 and line_splitted[2] <= 2000 and line_splitted[3] == "M" and line_splitted[4]== "CA":
print(line_splitted)
else:
    continue
```

And this is the result:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-d4b5d798cf33> in <module>
      8     line_splitted = line.strip().split(",")
      9     if line_splitted[1] == "Max":
---> 10         if line_splitted[1] == "Max" and line_splitted[2] >= 1950 and line_splitted[2] <= 2000 and line_splitted[3] == "M" and line_splitted[4]== "CA":
     11             print(line_splitted)
     12 

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I know that I should say to Python to convert the entry on index 2 in integers but I don´t know how to do it.Moreover I suspect that my solution is way too long in order to extract the informations I need. Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: See here about casting: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_casting.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (for your example) is probably to compare to a string:

```
and line_splitted[2] >= "1950"
```

This way you don't have to convert to integer first.

This will only work if all those string are exactly 4 characters long.